# What would be the voltage across the across the inductor just after time t=π/wo if the diode wasn't present?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, circuit-analysis, power-electronics, inductor

Basically, this is a diode and an L-C load. Now I was wondering if suppose the diode wasn't there and it was just a source Vs, inductor and capacitor.

Everything else would be the same except when the diode turns off at time t=π/wo. I think the voltage across the inductor would be -Vs if we consider the diode wasn't present at all. 
This is the pictures in my book for reference
[image]

[image]

Comment: The LC circuit will oscillate (series resonant circuit) forever but in reality, the circuit will oscillation time depend on the Q factor (approximately the number of cycles of ringing).  What is the book title?

Comment: @G36 The book is Power Electronics by P.S Bimbhra

Answer (score 0):

The behavior till t=π/wo should be same with or without the diode (if the diode is ideal.) As you can see in the book, the diode does not appear in the equations. Just after this instance,the capacitor voltage would still be 2*Vs as it cannot change instantaneously. So you are right, the inductor voltage has to be -Vs just after t=π/wo. After that, in the ideal situation, the voltage and current would continue to ring indefinitely as there is no resistance to damp the circuit.